# synchronizing ArrayList and wait

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I'm synchronizing ArrayList used by 2 threads. notify and wait pattern. the thread notified     but the arrayList contain the old values Although the other thread prints new values.

Th1:

```
  synchronized( pairsBarBuffers ) {

            try {
                pairsBarBuffers.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Th2:

```
    synchronized (pairs15MBarBuffers) {

         if( countSamples == 0 ){
             return;
         }

        updateBarBuffer( pairs15MBarBuffers , countSamples );

        pairs15MBarBuffers.notify();

        countSamples = 0;   

    }
```

Comment: Your code examples don't make any sense. It seems two different lists are used? Please post a compilable example that demonstrates the problem (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can't post all the code its huge. basically im passing the same array(reference) just the name is different in each one of the threads.

Comment: Did you read the link I provided? If you had, you'd realise I wasn't asking for all your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to synchronize explicitly:

```
Using Collections.synchronizedList() method
Using thread-safe variant of ArrayList: CopyOnWriteArrayList
```